# NodeJs /etc/environment not seeing file changes despite successful echo $variable

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, nginx, environment-variables, pm2

I have a digital ocean droplet running Ubuntu with Nodejs, nginx and Pm2 to reload on crash.

The site works successfully in the sense that it loads my script but unfortunately it does not seem to pick up the latest changes I have done to the `/etc/environment` file variable despite having rebooted and shut down my server. I have also tried source `/etc/environment` with no success.

The strange part is that my server returns the old values of the `/etc/environment` file rather then the latest.

And when I run in shell `echo $thevariable` it shows me the updated value.

So it almost looks like the environmental variable has been cached...

Any ideas to how I can get my local environment variable seen by my nodejs server that would be really appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Somehow figured it out. In order to dump those local variables and refresh them you have to do a `pm2 delete #` where # is the id number.

Then when you run a new `pm2 start server.js` that takes into account the updated variables...

Answer (score 0):

Restart pm2 process with **--update-env** argument.